# How to call api in every 5 mins in background Flutter dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, http, flutter-web

I have tried with timer and call api in every 5 mins. But it's blocking other api call. Can someone please guide me ?

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with 
WidgetsBindingObserver {

 int _timerCounter = 0;

 Timer? _timer;


@override
void initState() {
try {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this);

  _timer = new Timer.periodic(
      new Duration(milliseconds: 100000), _incrementTimerCounter);
} catch (error, s) {
  Functions.recordError(error, s);
}
}
```

At time of Init, assigned timer and when app resumed state that time also assigned timer again.

```
 @override
 void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
 
  if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    _timer = new Timer.periodic(
        new Duration(milliseconds: 100000), 
   _incrementTimerCounter);
   
  } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
    _timer!.cancel();
  }
  
 }

void _incrementTimerCounter(Timer t) {

  if (!mounted) return;
  print("_timerCounter is $_timerCounter");
  refereshData();
  
  _timerCounter++;

}

Future refereshData() async {

  if (!mounted) return;
    if (await Utils.checkConnection()) {
      var data = Provider.of<ProviderPostData>(context, listen: 
    false);
      await data.postDataCall(context);
    
    }
    
     }
    
   }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container();
   }
 }
```

I have called api through timer. every 2 minutes I'm calling api in background. It's working well but it's blocking other api request as well.
Thanks

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: @roosi I have update my code. please have a look!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit of the blocking issue? Don't see any other calls.

Comment: @user18309290 Means, I have a call background api from home screen, when I navigate to other screen, that time call other api's. But that other page api's call not firing untill background api's call response.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to create a recursive `callApi` function like this:

```dart
void callApi() {
  Future.delayed(const Duration(minutes: 5), (){
      // call API functionality 
      callApi();
  });
}
```

It's a little bit obscure though.

If I were you, I'd go with Firebase Functions which can be scheduled. Unfortunately it requires Firebase Blaze plan
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions